# Will Oracle9iDialect used for oracle 12C?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My hibernate version is 4.2.18 and oracle is 11G
The dialect used to connect to 11G is **Oracle9iDialect**
Now we are upgrading the DB to 12C, should my dialect also gets changed to Oracle10gDialect or is it okay if I continue with Oracle9iDialect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try continue using `Oracle9iDialect` and see what happens but that's definitely not a good idea as Hibernate 4.2 is a legacy (4.2.18 was released in early 2015). You should update Hibernate and use [`Oracle12cDialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle12cDialect.java) which is now provided.